# Rep-league link on local meta's shouldn't be there - no where to go!

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

If you visit the **users** page on a child meta, there is the link at the bottom for `weekly / monthly / yearly reputation leagues`.

Given these child metas don't have thier own leagues, or even rep, these links seem a little surplus to requirements. They also lead to 404...

For example, clicking on the one on [meta SU user page](http://meta.superuser.com/users) points you to the following URL:
https://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/meta-superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have now been fixed.

Comment: Feel free to flag your request with reason `status-completed` :)

Comment: sorry, didn't realize there was a request for this or I would have marked it completed.

Comment: @badp - I thought only the mod's could use the `status-*` tags - and it's done now anyway.

Comment: I said "flag", not "tag".

Comment: @Badp So you did. Urgh, it's too early for *reading*... And I'll try to remember that if that's the case again in the future. Sorry, and thanks!